# Default Android Drawer to more activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to make more activities with the same drawer, but apparently everytime I load a new activity it redirects me back to whatever the activity has the index in the variable position.

To move from activities via the main activity drawer I got no problems, here is the code of the main activity:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        Intent newIntent;
        if (position == 1){
            newIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(newIntent);
        }
```

When I try to change the same method on the new activity

```
if (position == 0){
                newIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(newIntent);
            }
```

it does not even wait for me to selection, just automaticqally redirects me to the SecondActivity without letting me open up the drawer. I am using the default code for drawers in fragments. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without having the code, but it might be because you are setting the current position to 0 at some point of the drawer initialization, causing a call to `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected`. If this is the case, maybe you could first set the initial position and, after that, set the `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` callback.

Also, if you are using the Drawer pattern and you want the same drawer in diferent activities, why you don't try to use a main activity and fragments instead of many activities?

This way, you could load different contents and preserve the original drawer.